# dateformat and closeOnSelect seem to have no effect for ionic-datepciker

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using this date picker for my Ionic app:

> https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

Two of the options I have set seem to have no effect.

- Even though I have set `dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd'` the date in the datepicker is shown in the default format dd-MM-yyyy.
- Even though I have set `closeOnSelect: true`, the date picker does not close on select and the set button is visible.

Here is my code:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.datepickerObject = {
    titleLabel: 'Title',  //Optional
    inputDate: new Date(),  //Optional
    mondayFirst: true,  //Optional
    //disabledDates: disabledDates, //Optional
    templateType: 'popup', //Optional
    to: new Date(),
    callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
        datePickerCallback(val);
    },
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd', //Optional
    closeOnSelect: true //Optional
  };

  var datePickerCallback = function (val) {
    if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
      // no date selected
    } else {
      $scope.datepickerObject.inputDate = val;
    }
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize the date format you need to specify that in your html file:

```
    <ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject">
      <button class="button"> {{datepickerObject.inputDate | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'}}</button>
    </ionic-datepicker>
```

Also, in the current release- 0.9.0- closeOnSelect dosen't work.

https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker/issues/110

Regards